# Unable to commit files in Gitlab-ci

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying things out with gitlab-ci the first time. So far it worked well and as expected but since I'm trying to use the maven release plugin I've got some issues using git through the maven release plugin.

When I try to execute the mvn release:prepare release:perform goals I got the folloing error which I don't fully understand.

```
[INFO] 11/17 prepare:scm-commit-release
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers' && 'git' 'add' '--' 'pom.xml'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--show-prefix'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers' && 'git' 'status' '--porcelain' '.'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? .m2/repository/
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers' && 'git' 'commit' '--verbose' '-F' '/tmp/maven-scm-726414461.commit'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers' && 'git' 'symbolic-ref' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers' && 'git' 'push' 'jan-stefan:********@gitlab.com:gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers.git' 'refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.199 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-23T00:09:10Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M6:prepare (default-cli) on project gehrbeck-problems: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] ssh: Could not resolve hostname jan-stefan: Name or service not known
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I use the following gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
image: maven:3.9.0-amazoncorretto-19 # Set the docker image gitlab is using

variables:
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository/
    - target/

stages:
  - release

release-artifact:
  stage: release
  only:
    - main
  #when: manual
  script:
    # Installing and configuring git.
    - echo "installing git"
    - yum install -y git
    - git --version
    # Configuring git instance
    - git config --global user.name "$git_config_user_name"
    - git config --global user.email "$git_config_user_email"
    - git config --global init.defaultBranch "$git_config_init_default_branch"
    - git config --list
    # Adding the ssh key to successfully commit the changes to git when doing a release later.
    # install or update the ssh client
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( yum update -y && yum install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - chmod 400 "$ssh_private_key"
    - ssh-add "$ssh_private_key"
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    # Performing the actual release.
    - git checkout -B "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    # Disable strict host key checking in the dockerized environment
    #- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    # print git remote origin url to check for errors
    - git config --get remote.origin.url
    - git remote set-url origin https://$GIT_CI_USER:$GIT_CI_PASS@gitlab.com/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -DskipTests=true -Dusername="$git_username" -Dpassword="$git_password" release:prepare release:perform
```

I don't use any custom runners. I'm using the default one that gitlab is providing to everyone.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's the used project pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gehrbeck.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>gehrbeck-problems</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Settings for release -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>com-gehrbeck-repository-releases</id>
            <name>Gehrbeck Repository</name>
            <url>https://reposilite.gehrbeck.com/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>com-gehrbeck-repository-snapshots</id>
            <name>Gehrbeck Repository</name>
            <url>https://reposilite.gehrbeck.com/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@gitlab.com:gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitlab.com:gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/gehrbeck/gehrbeck-answers.git</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You've added git remote using http format (which should be fine), but Maven's release plugin doesn't understand it, and tries to ssh to the host instead.

Comment: m-release-p use scm url from project developerConnection - https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html

Comment: @kenorb Is there a way to tell the Maven release plugin explicitly to use it?

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski I dont quite understand how you mean this? In the maven pom.xml it not possible to add a scm configuration inside a profile.

So Just added it as shown now in the question.